# How to convert milliseconds to formatted time string in QML without timezone offset?

Tags: javascript, qt, datetime, qml

I'm trying to convert milliseconds to a formatted time string using the following:

```
function getTimeString(timeMs) {
    return Qt.formatTime(new Date(timeMs), "h:mm:ss");
}
```

The problem is, when I give it 1 hour worth of time, instead of displaying `1:00:00` it displays `20:00:00`. Two hours similarly displays `21:00:00`. This is because of the timezone offset built into the Date object. There are some functions to remove the timezone offset that sound promising, but fall short, such as:

- Date.getUTCDate() which turns the QML Date object into a javascript Date object that can no longer be passed into Qt.formatTime(), and javascript seems to have no suitable alternative time formatting.
- Date.toUTCString() which doesn't take a format, so I would need some string manipulation to cut the unwanted parts out.

I could always just use repeated divisions and manually build the string from that, but what I have is fairly short and clear, and I'd like to keep it that way if possible.

Comment: Here is an already provided solution. It works for me in my project
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35890816/5903276
You can try this

Comment: @RamkumarR While not a bad solution, it has to same problem as Date.toUTCString(). I'll have to do string manipulations (though not many) to get what I want instead of being able to use a custom format. For instance, I'll have to check and conditionally remove the leading 0, which "h:mm:ss" takes care of automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by manually adding the timezone offset and converting to locale string, which allows to add a format:

```
var date = new Date(timestamp)
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + date.getTimezoneOffset())

return date.toLocaleString(Qt.locale(), "dd. MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

Not sure though, if this works with all timezones, I have only tested de_DE